# Dynamic products in Apple In-App Purchase

Tags: ios

How to deal with dynamic products in In-App purchase? We have an existing website having and admin panel where user adds his/her courses. There are thousands of courses and every day lots of courses created there.

Its not possible to add those courses to Apple In-App Purchase portal. Is there any other solution to use dynamic products to In-App Purchase? there are discounts and promotional coupons also applied. Is there any API exists which we can configure to our admin panel and course will automatically added to In-App?

Please help me and save my life...

Comment: You may consider having users buy "credits" which could in turn be used to buy the products. Or you could just create one in-app purchase for each possible price. But double-check App Store guidelines to make sure you still comply.

Comment: Also, you can use Application Loader to build upload many IAPs, or Transporter to upload them from the command line. Don't forget though that new IAPs need a screenshot and to be reviewed, so that may not be the best option for you.

Comment: Thanks @jcaron i will try this

Comment: Is there any command line tool available, from which i can login and add IAP products to iTunes connect automatically from my server?

Comment: Yes, it's called Transporter. You'll find details in the resources and help section on iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four steps to add multiple IAPs to iTunes Connect using the Application Loader (Version 3.0 at the time of writing):

1. Open the Application Loader and access the template via the menu
   "File" --> "Open App Import Template". Copy the template somewhere
   else and open it with Excel or something similar.
2. Add all your IAP Information and save the file as a .txt. (Leave the
   screenshot column empty.)
3. Create a directory where you add screenshots for each IAP. The
   filename should match the product id of the IAP item. Example:
   "com.companyname.appname.productId.png".
4. Use the import function of the Application Loader, where you will
   provide the .txt and will be asked for the screenshots.

If everything goes well your IAPs are now added and you can open iTunes Connect to submit them for review.

Hope this will help you. or you can use some command line tool provided by iTunes connect called Transporter. more details here http://itunespartner.apple.com/en/movies/faq/Transporter_Getting%20Set%20Up#!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is nothing like that. You have to manually create product identifiers for in-app purchase. The product identifiers for which added in portal, those only works.